# Nested quotes in string with OCaml?

Tags: string, ocaml

I have been trying to pass a string as an argument that has double quotes in it. For example, I want the input to be a string saying I am programming in "OCaml":

```
"I am programming in "OCaml""
```

That is what i want to be able to pass. I tried using some lexical conventions but had no luck. I don't want to change the quotes around OCaml.

I have tried

```
"\"I am programming in "OCaml"\"
```

And a couple of variations of this. Any tips on how to pass it?

Answer (score 10):

You should escape the quotes *inside* the string, as with any other character that needs escaping, not the delimiters themselves:

```
"I am programming in \"OCaml\""
```

Alternatively, you can use a quoted string, which does not require (or allow) escaping and might be closer to what you were trying for:

```
{|I am programming in "OCaml"|}
```

For more details, see [the section on string literals in the OCaml manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/lex.html#sss:stringliterals).

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of literal strings containing double quotes:

```
"I am programming in \"OCaml\""
{|I am programming "OCaml"|}
```