# How to write the character '"'

Tags: string, ocaml

I would like to use a string which contains the character in ocaml '"', for example the string
"This character '"' is interesting".
I've written "This character '\"' is interesting". But it doesn't work...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nested quotes in string with OCaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63223119/nested-quotes-in-string-with-ocaml)

Comment: @glennsl no, it outputs "'\\"'"

Comment: _What:_ outputs that? Are you doing this in the toplevel? If so, that's just how the toplevel prints it. Like in code. The `\` isn't actually in the string.

Comment: okay, that's probably the reason, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting it like you did is working, but you could also use the new string delimiter:

```ml
let () =
  print_endline "This character '\"' is interesting";
  print_endline {|This character '"' is interesting|}
```